# Symfony php framework based photo/video gallery script

Tags: php, symfony1, gallery

I am looking for some open source or commercial script which can allow me to have a gallery component in my website. This component will allow users to publish photos
(add title, album name, small description) and also let them provide their video urls from youtube. For youtube videos also they will provide the title, album name and small description.

Another nice to have feature would be to let users vote on these photos and videos.

Does anyone know of any script that can be easily integrated in symfony php framework?

Rgds,
Sapan

Comment: it sounds a bit too bespoke. Looks like they you'll have to write it yourself. Alas, I know of no plugin that does this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing written that meets your exact requirements - but there this could be a starting point - or at least give you some ideas of how to store / manage assets -> http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfAssetsLibraryPlugin